# Combinatorics - distribute n different objects into 2 groups where one specific group has to have an even number of objects?

Tags: combinatorics

How do I even start calculating this? I don't have an intuition.

Comment: The group into which the last object is placed is determined by the number of objects in the specific group.

Answer (score 1):

$$
\begin{aligned}
\left(1-1\right)^n&=\sum_{i=0}^{n}{\binom{n}{i}(-1)^{i}}\\
0&=\sum_{i_{even}}{\binom{n}{i}}-\sum_{i_{odd}}{\binom{n}{i}}\\
\sum_{i_{odd}}{\binom{n}{i}}&= \sum_{i_{even}}{\binom{n}{i}}\\
\\
\left(1+1\right)^{n}&=\sum_{i=0}^{n}{\binom{n}{i}}\\
2^{n}&= \sum_{i_{even}}{\binom{n}{i}}+\sum_{i_{odd}}{\binom{n}{i}}\\
2^{n}&=2\sum_{i_{even}}{\binom{n}{i}}\\
2^{n-1}&=\sum_{i_{even}}{\binom{n}{i}}
\end{aligned}
$$

If You do not want any group to have $0$ members, $2^{n-1}-1$ for odd $n$ and $2^{n-1}-2$ for even $n$.

## interpretation of the result:

Say group $A$ need even numbers while  group $B$ is the other group.

If $n$ is odd, just divide the objects into two unordered groups ($2^{n-1}$ ways). There is always one even group and one odd group. Label the even one as $A$ and the other as $B$. Then subtract by $1$ to remove distribution in which $A$ has $0$ members. Hence $2^{n-1}-1$

If $n$ is even, first separate one object, then divide the remaining $n-1$ into two unordered groups ($2^{n-2}$ ways). There is always one even group and one odd group. We can either label the even group as $A$ and the odd group + that one object we separated as $B$ or the other way. Then subtract by $2$ to remove distribution in which $A$ or $B$ has $0$ members. Hence $2\times 2^{n-2}-2=2^{n-1}-1$